# Rotate 3D rigged human model around pelvis root node while keeping feet planted

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d, collada, scenekit

I am currently using iOS's Scenekit along with an imported collada file from Cheetah 3D.

I have a simple rigged body with the root attached to the pelvis.  All the children nodes are attached to the pelvis (spine, legs).

The problem occurs when I try to rotate the pelvis say 45 degrees.  The entire model rotates 45 degrees and the feet then wind up above the floor.  How can I keep the feet planted on the floor.  Do I need to make the change in the Cheetah 3D or make the change in  objective-c adjusting SCNNode properties manually?

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pelvis is the root of the node hierarchy, rotating it rotates everything—that's how hierarchical modeling is supposed to work. Sounds like what you want is for other parts of your skeleton to move relative to the pelvis—so look for its child nodes and rotate those.

You can do this in code, but working with whatever tool you used to create the skeleton or with Xcode's SceneKit editor might help you get a visual feel for what your code needs to do.